# Cipher mode CTR is not available in installed OpenSSL library PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I'm using the [crypto](https://github.com/bukka/php-crypto) library for encrypting data for Google Chrome notifications in PHP.

I have this `OpenSSL` version: `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

When I try to run: `$cipher = Cipher::aes(Cipher::MODE_GCM, 128);`

I get this error:

> Cipher mode CTR is not available in installed OpenSSL library.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Don't use the FIPS version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Can this be the problem?

Comment: It certainly could be. FIPS mode disables a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, I think, two things going on here. You're doing this:

```
Cipher::aes(Cipher::MODE_GCM, 128);
```

And you're getting an error mode that says:

> Cipher mode CTR is not available in installed OpenSSL library.

GCM and CTR are two distinct modes from an API level. GCM is at a basic level CTR mode with a [MAC based on Galois field multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Mathematical_basis).

GCM is failing because CTR mode is not available.

Why isn't it available? This could be because you're using the FIPS version of OpenSSL (`OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`). It could also be because your version of OpenSSL is over 3 years old (and is likely vulnerable to Heartbleed). The happy place right now is `OpenSSL 1.0.2g`.

Comment: Thank you! Installing OpenSSL 1.0.2g fixed it!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it.